# spring mongodb - aggregation pipeline into java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I wrote the following aggregation pipeline that returns the most liked items in my users collection

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$favoriteItems"},
  {$group: {
    _id: "$favoriteItems" ,
    likes: { $sum: 1 }
  }},
  {$sort: { likes: -1 }}
])
```

Here is a prototype document from my users collection:

```
{
  "_id": "5a6df13552f42a34dcca9aa6",
  "username": "user1",
  "favoriteItems": [
    {
      "_id": "5a0c6b2dfd3eb67969316d6d",
      "name": "item1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a0c680afd3eb67969316d0b",
      "name": "item2"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my attempt at doing the same in java:

```
public void getMostLikedItems () {
        UnwindOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("favoriteItems");
        GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("favoriteItems").sum("1").as("likes");
        SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "likes");

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(unwind, group, sort);
        AggregationResults<LikedItem > result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "users", LikedItem .class);
        for (LikedItem s: result) {
            System.out.println(s.getId() + ": " + s.getValue());
        }
    }
```

This is not yielding any output. What am i missing here?

**EDIT**
LikedItem.java

```
public class LikedItem {

    private Item id;
    private float value;
    // empty and full constructor + getters and setters

}
```

**EDIT 2**
Item class

```
public class Item{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type= GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    private GeoJsonPoint location;

    public Shop() { super(); }
    // full constructor + getters and setters
}
```

Comment: have you checked logs, what query has been fired?

Comment: @Saravana I see nothing in IDE console nor the mongod.exe log. Is there anywhere else I should check?

Comment: Its likely you're getting some output but it is not mapped. Can you add LikedItem to the post ? Try `Document result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "users", LikedItem.class).getRawResults();` to view what you get back from mongo

Comment: @Veeram, I editted my post to include LikedItem class.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ? Please also include item class.

Comment: @Veeram yes I did I still get an exception of type com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9. I included item class in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the incorrect method.

`sum` method takes reference and you get something like `"likes" : { "$sum" : "$1" }`.

Use `count` method instead to output `"likes" : { "$sum" : 1 }`

```
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("favoriteItems").count().as("likes");
```

Comment: thank you for pointing the function error. Right now I am getting an exception:

`com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }`

Comment: Also, my rest controller returns a description of the error which includes
`Command = { "aggregate" : "users" , "pipeline" : [ { "$unwind" : "$preferredShops"} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$preferredShops" , "likes" : { "$sum" : 1}}} , { "$sort" : { "likes" : -1}}]}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException:`